# I am using Angular 1 and I am trying to ng-hide my login button once a user is logged in?

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I know I am suppose to do and ng-hide="something", but I don't where to go from there.  Not sure if I have to also write another function in my logoutController or mainController.

```
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="logout" ng-click='logoutCtrl.logout()'>Logout</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

nav.html

```
function logoutController($state, AuthService) {
 var vm = this
  vm.logout = function () {

// call logout from service
AuthService.logout()
  .then(function () {
    $state.go('login')
  })
```

}
}

app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depend the way you're login works but you can do

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a ng-show="inNotLogged"ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="logout" ng-click='logoutCtrl.logout()'>Logout</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

and in your app.js `.run` set `$rootScope.isNotLogged = true;`then in your login method:

```
$rootScope.isNotLogged = false;
$scope.isNotLogged = $rootScope.isNotLogged;
```

so in tour lgout you will set

```
$scope.isNotLogged = true;
$rootScope.isNotLogged = $scope.isNotLogged;
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I changed my controller(code that already validates current user).